After use commitChanges in layer PyQGIS generate ERROR Failed to delete file qix
When I use commitChanges on a layer in PyQGIS then it generates ERROR 1: Failed to delete somefile.qix
I use it in the button method when I want to save the edit changes in the layer. Here is the code:
def uloz_zmeny(self):
    aktualnaVrstva = self.view.currentLayer()
    aktualnaVrstva.commitChanges()
    aktualnaVrstva.startEditing()
    self.buffer = aktualnaVrstva.editBuffer()

The error is generated after the command:
aktualnaVrstva.commitChanges()

It seems that the changes will be saved, but I don't know why this error is generated. I am using PyQGIS 3.34.

are you on windows?

I do not know why it fails, but the edits make the GDAL style spatial index (.qix) of shapefile invalid and it should be deleted.

Yes, I'm on Windows
